# Google groups + Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-groups

I am in the process of writing a RoR (Ruby on Rails) app for my Google group. The ideal situation is to be able to access the pre-existing group data (group members, calendar etc)  available on Google - I would like to be able to manage (CRUD) the Google group through the RoR application. Is this feasible? What other options do I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/ it provides an api to manage users, groups, and devices

Comment: which option is better? option1: to make api calls during application run time for data manipulation or option2: to get information from api and store locally?

Comment: i think option 1 will do since the request will be made when need arises which will affect load time like the second option will do